# using Trino to access his table and passing list/tuple to dynamically filter query in the where clause

Tags: python, database, trino

I have encountered an issue using dynamic filtering and passing a list/tuple into the where clause, and I am not very experienced in python so please help me.

I am using conn_hms = trino.dbapi.connect to HMS table, and I define the read function below:

```
def read_hms(conn_hms, q, start_day, end_day, sf, query):
    cur = conn_hms.cursor()
    cur.execute(q, params=[start_day, end_day, sf, query])
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    column_names = [desc[0] for desc in cur.description]
    data = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=column_names)
    return data
```

so i will pass in start/end day, sf, and query into the sql later (query parameter is the list/tuple i want to filter in sql)

```
sf_choice = str(market.value)
start = start_date.value.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
end = end_date.value.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

genre_converted = """
            SELECT query
                  ,kind_type
                  ,COUNT(*) AS frequencies
            FROM
                table abc
            WHERE
                DATE_TRUNC('day', date)>= from_iso8601_date(?) and DATE_TRUNC('day', date)<= from_iso8601_date(?)
                AND market = ?
                AND query in ?
            GROUP BY 1,2
            order by query, COUNT(*) desc
        """
top_genre = read_hms(conn_hms, genre_converted, start, end, sf_choice, queries)
```

Until the point i make query a list/ tuple, this works, but now they are returning syntex error like "TrinoUserError: TrinoUserError(type=USER_ERROR, name=SYNTAX_ERROR, message="line 14:27: mismatched input 'in'. Expecting: 'AND', 'EXCEPT', 'FETCH', 'GROUP', 'HAVING', 'INTERSECT', 'LIMIT', 'OFFSET', 'OR', 'ORDER', 'UNION', 'WINDOW', ", query_id=20220228_004211_00817_et3jr)".

Could you please help me on this?

Comment: you may want to check your column names.. when I use your code to try and test it seems to produce duplicate column names